# VAAPI and multiple video cards

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, vaapi

I recently got a new (actually, a second-hand, but new to me) Inspiron 5548 with an Intel Core i7-5500U that also has an AMD Radeon R7 M260/M265 card.

Everything works fine with my Ubuntu 17.04 (pre-release), but I have a "problem" that was also present since I first installed Ubuntu 16.10, namely:

`vainfo` only shows me information regarding my Intel graphics card, but not regarding my other card. I believe that I have all the packages installed, and have the following vaapi drivers installed:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/*_drv_video.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2113216 Nov 10 17:34 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
-rw-r--r-- 3 root root 4416200 Feb  6 05:47 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 May 11  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so -> vdpau_drv_video.so
-rw-r--r-- 3 root root 4416200 Feb  6 05:47 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
-rw-r--r-- 3 root root 4416200 Feb  6 05:47 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 May 11  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/s3g_drv_video.so -> vdpau_drv_video.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   97224 May 11  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vdpau_drv_video.so
```

Here is the output of `vainfo`, which picks up my Intel integrated card:

```
$ vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.3)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Broadwell - 1.7.3
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
```

When I request the output using other drivers, this is what I get:

```
$ LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'radeonsi'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
ilo: driver missing
ilo: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 2
vaInitialize failed with error code 2 (resource allocation failed),exit
```

## Some context about the hardware and software

The output from [inxi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/inxi) is the following:

```
# inxi -v2
System:    Host: inspiron-5548 Kernel: 4.10.0-9-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: MATE 1.17.2
           Distro: Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
Machine:   Device: portable System: Dell product: Inspiron 5548 v: A07 serial: 6B7H542
           Mobo: Dell model: 0YDTG3 v: A00 serial: .6B7H542.BR1183055L0209. UEFI: Dell v: A07 date: 06/23/2016
Battery    BAT1: charge: 37.3 Wh 100.0% condition: 37.3/38.4 Wh (97%)
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U (-HT-MCP-) speed/max: 799/3000 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: modesetting,ati,amdgpu (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           tty size: 190x49 Advanced Data: N/A for root
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller driver: r8169
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (16.4% used)
           ID-1: model: ST1000LM014
Info:      Processes: 232 Uptime: 7 days Memory: 2374.9/15960.3MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.8
```

Even after googling a lot, I could not find how to see the VAAPI information of the AMD side of my system and I would love to find out how to discover this (especially for transcoding things with ffmpeg).

## Extra information

After the helpful hint by @Brainiarc7, using the variable setting `DRI_PRIME=1` makes the output change considerably:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'radeonsi'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.3)
vainfo: Driver version: mesa gallium vaapi
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Is the hardware being used even though the driver is `mesa gallium vaapi` or is it a software decoder/placeholder? That's progress, anyway. I find it surprising that there are only a few supported profile/entrypoints (but that's perhaps the driver not exposing if, indeed, the hardware is being used).

I will gladly provide any further information that is deemed necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the AMD GPU, you'd need to call up vainfo as shown below:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi vainfo
```

Now, print the output and see if anything changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The output does change, but now I am not really sure if it works or not. I will update my question with the output, so that more people can see it in the future. As I stated before, I will send any information that is required.

Comment: The best way to confirm if this works for you would be to compile FFmpeg with VAAPI enabled, and then try transcoding a video with it. gstreamer-vaapi also provides such a utility.

Comment: Right, thanks. I could not (yet) use ffmpeg to transcode a video (it says that the encoding profile could not be found), but I guess that this is related to the final part of the output that I listed, where only 3 profile/entrypoints were listed (and none contained H264). I'm accepting the answer, though.